# Drawbacks of increasing PHP memory limit

Tags: php

Recently my app started throwing fatal errors regarding exhaustion of the max allowed memory. After some research, I found out that the limit is set in the `.htaccess` file and it sets to 64m.

The tried allocation is of around 80MB, and we are able to provide these resources, but I wanted to ask the community if increasing the value of this variable is a good solution to the problem. 
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on what your script is doing :) It sounds like the increase in your case was quite small (from 64 to 80 MB, I'd recommend sticking to the powers of two though and upping it to 128MB btw.) so it shouldn't make much of a difference for modern machines. But to know if it was the right thing to do you need to find out why you needed more memory.

If your processing simply requires more memory (eg. you're processing uploaded files in memory, or decoding big json or xml structures or doing something else which is memory intensive) upping your limit is ok and common.

If however your application has memory leaks or is written in an inefficient way then upping the memory limit is just masking the problem and not solving it. You'll likely keep running into this issue and end up upping the memory all the time which is not feasible.

If you don't know what caused the sudden increase in memory consumption I'd recommend profiling your application using e.g. [xhprof](http://xhprof.io/). You can also look at the last few changes to your app and see what might have caused it. If you can justify it then give your script more memory, otherwise try optimising your code first.

Comment: The memory limit could be set to even a higher value. 256-512 MB is not uncommon. But for the rest Kat is absolutely right; make sure you can justify it.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is typically deployed in a way that a PHP process serves multiple request after another. During a single request a script can now allocate memory. At the end this memory will be free'd. So far so good. Now most operating systems are built in a way to keep memory, which was allocated bound to a process, even when freed. The assumption there is that a programmed which required memory once will need the amount again and it's cheaper to keep it available to the process than taking it back. Thus in a PHP deployment it might happen, that one request takes a lot of memory and then the memory is bound to the process and not available to the system anymore. Additionally it's a possible indication for a bug if some process takes a lot more memory than anticipated. So for those two things the memory_limit serves as safety net.

If your application needs more memory it's generally fine to increase the limit. The **absolute** maximum value is dependant on the system (`available RAM` / `number of worker processes` might be a rough formula, rough as it doesn't include other memory needed) Typically you should only increase by an amount needed.

Of course when changing this you have to remember when moving to other systems. Also typically less memory usage means faster execution thus you should try to see if you can optimise your code.

---

Side note: I purposely simplified the memory model above, ignoring virtual memory pages and how operating systems optimize there